# General sparse iterative solver libraries

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

What are some of the better libraries for large sparse iterative (conjugate gradient, MINRES, GMRES, etc.) linear algebra system solving?  I've often coded my own routines, but I'm interested to know which "off-the-shelf" packages people prefer.  I've heard of PETSc, TAUCS, IML++, and a few others.  I'm wondering how these stack up, and what else is out there.  My preference is for ease of use, and freely available software.

Answer (score 4):

Victor Eijkhout's [Overview of Iterative Linear System Solver Packages](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/iterative-survey/) would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: That's great, though a little outdated.

Answer (score 4):

You may also wish to look at Trilinos
http://trilinos.sandia.gov/

It is designed by some great software craftsman, using modern
design techniques.

Moreover, from within Trilinos, you can call PetsC if you desire.

Answer (score 2):

NIST has some sparse Linear Algebra software you can download
here: http://math.nist.gov/sparselib++/ and here: http://math.nist.gov/spblas/

I haven't used those packages myself, but I've heard good things about them.

Comment: SparseLib++ is just a sparse matrix class library.  The relevant iterative solver library is IML++ ( http://math.nist.gov/iml++/ ), which was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/](https://web.archive.org/web/20101206103301/http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/)

> UMFPACK is a set of routines for
>   solving unsymmetric sparse linear
>   systems, Ax=b, using the Unsymmetric
>   MultiFrontal method. Written in
>   ANSI/ISO C, with a MATLAB (Version 6.0
>   and later) interface. Appears as a
>   built-in routine (for lu, backslash,
>   and forward slash) in MATLAB. Includes
>   a MATLAB interface, a C-callable
>   interface, and a Fortran-callable
>   interface. Note that "UMFPACK" is
>   pronounced in two syllables, "Umph
>   Pack". It is not "You Em Ef Pack".

I'm using it for FEM code.

Comment: Thanks, although I believe UMFPACK is a direct solver (not an iterative solver).

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Microsoft's Solver Foundation. It's free to cheap for even pretty big problems.  The unlimited version is industrial strength and is based on Gurobi and of course isn't cheap.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation

Comment: From your link, it seems that Microsoft's Solver Foundation is a linear and nonlinear optimization library, which is connected to numerical linear algebra, but is not the right tool for solving the linear system `Ax = b` for the vector `x` given a sparse matrix `A` and the vector `b`.